# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, numberformatexception

I want when the user press an image navigate to details fragment but when press its crash and show the error of NumberFormat even though I put toInt to handle the exception
I tried to do some solutions here but nothing work

This is my code for the detail fragment:

```
package com.example.finalcapstone_nomapp.main.view

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.os.StrictMode
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.finalcapstone_nomapp.R
import com.example.finalcapstone_nomapp.databinding.FragmentDetailsBinding
import com.example.finalcapstone_nomapp.model.Result
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.lang.NumberFormatException


class DetailsFragment : Fragment() {
      private lateinit var binding : FragmentDetailsBinding
      private val recipesViewModel : RecipesViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private val favoriteRecipesViewModel : FavoriteRecipesViewModel by activityViewModels()
    lateinit var favoriteItem : Result


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

       binding = FragmentDetailsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       
        val result = Result(
            recipesViewModel.likes.toInt(),
            true,
            true,
            true,
            recipesViewModel.id.toInt(),
            recipesViewModel.image,
            recipesViewModel.ready,
            "url",
            recipesViewModel.description,
            recipesViewModel.title,
            recipesViewModel.vegan,
            true,
            true
        )
        observers()

        binding.addImageView.setOnClickListener(){
            observers()
            favoriteRecipesViewModel.addFavoriteRecipe(result,"")
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_detailsFragment_to_FavoriteFragment)

            if (binding.addImageView.isPressed){
               binding.addImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.addimageviewblack)
            }
        }
        binding.recipeDetailsImageView2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(favoriteItem.sourceUrl))
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    fun observers(){
        recipesViewModel.selectedRecipeMutabileLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,{

            var selectedItem = it
        //================================================================//
            Picasso.get().load(it.image).into(binding.recipeDetailsImageView2)

        //================================================================//
            binding.detailTitleTextView.text = it.title
            binding.detailLikesTextView.text = it.aggregateLikes.toString()
            binding.detailsTimeTextView.text = it.readyInMinutes.toString()

        //=================================================================//
            binding.summaryTextView.text = it.summary
         //==================================================================//

            when {
                it.vegetarian -> {
                    binding.detailVegetarianImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.check)
                    binding.detailVeganTextView.setTextColor(R.color.green)
                }
                it.vegan -> {

                    binding.detailVeganImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.check)
                    binding.detailVeganTextView.setTextColor(R.color.green)
                }
                it.dairyFree -> {
                    binding.detailDairyfreeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.check)
                    binding.detailDairyfreeTextView.setTextColor(R.color.green)

                }
                it.glutenFree -> {
                    binding.detailGlutenfreeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.check)
                    binding.detailGlutenfreeTextView.setTextColor(R.color.green)

                }
                it.veryHealthy -> {
                    binding.detailHealthyImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.check)
                    binding.detailGlutenfreeTextView.setTextColor(R.color.green)

                }
                it.cheap -> {
                    binding.detailCheapImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.check)
                    binding.detailCheapTextView.setTextColor(R.color.green)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the recipesViewModel:

```
package com.example.finalcapstone_nomapp.main.view

import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.finalcapstone_nomapp.main.adapters.RecipesAdapter
import com.example.finalcapstone_nomapp.model.Result
import com.example.finalcapstone_nomapp.repository.ApiRepository
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlin.Exception

private const val TAG = "RecipesViewModel"

class RecipesViewModel : ViewModel() {

    // Getting instance from ApiRepository with companion object function

    private val apiRepo = ApiRepository.get()

    private lateinit var recipesAdapter : RecipesAdapter


    // livedata
    val recipesLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Result>>()
    val recipesErrorLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    
    var selectedRecipeMutabileLiveData = MutableLiveData<Result>()

    var likes = ""
    var id = ""
    var image = ""
    var ready = 0
    var description = ""
    var title = ""
    var vegan = true


    //=========================================================//
    fun callRecipes(){
     //coroutine in this scope will live as long the view model is alive.
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
          // use try and catch to handle http exceptions

            try {

                val response = apiRepo.getRecipes("String",true,true,"String")

                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    response.body()?.run {
                        Log.d(TAG,this.toString())

                        recipesLiveData.postValue(this.results)
                        Log.d(TAG, "success response ${response.body()}")
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG,"NOT SUCCESS ${response.message()}")
                    recipesErrorLiveData.postValue(response.message())

                }
            } catch (e : Exception){
                Log.d(TAG,e.message.toString())
                recipesErrorLiveData.postValue(e.message.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here:

```
var likes = ""
var id = ""

recipesViewModel.likes.toInt(),
recipesViewModel.id.toInt(),
```

try to skip parsing when string is empty or blank

```
...
safeToInt(recipesViewModel.id)

fun safeToInt(string: String): Int {
    if (string.isNotBlank()) {
        return string.toInt()
    } else {
// or other logic
        return 0
    }
}
...
```

Comment: i tried to use this fun on the observer but it did not work it show the same error

Comment: please add the whole exception stack

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.finalcapstone_nomapp, PID: 17906
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
        at com.example.finalcapstone_nomapp.main.view.DetailsFragment.onViewCreated(DetailsFragment.kt:56)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for late Appearance, Please Read this for safe type primitive casting.

The **toInt()** method helps to parse the string to an Int numerical value. However, It throws a NumberFormatException exception if it finds the string is not a correct representation of a number value.

The **toIntOrNull()** method parses the string to an Int and returns null if it finds string doesn’t belong valid numerical representation.